# Google analytics works local and not works in aws s3, why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, google-analytics

I Built static website with node and some react components. 
When I start application locally, everything works fine (including google analytics tracking), but executing in AWS S3 bucket, google analytics does not work.

What I'm not seeing? Or what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly doable, but harder.  Amazon has its own logfile format that you can enable, and you can feed the results into any reporting engine you like.

I've written about how to do that here:

https://www.expatsoftware.com/articles/2007/11/roll-your-own-web-stats-for-amazon-s3.html

If you just want the reports today, there are a handful of 3rd party services that will do it all for you, so if you have ~$10/month to spend that's probably the best solution.

S3stat (https://www.s3stat.com/) is my suggestion.  But then it should be since it's also my product.